# skip over CORS in Spring and configure project to work with Aptana

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, spring, tomcat

I am developing a client application using Aptana IDE and a REST application using Spring.

By default, the server from Aptana runs on 127.0.0.1:8020 and the Spring is running on 127.0.0.1:8080.

If I try to send an AJAX call from the client app to the Spring app, it will complain about CORS.

I am running the Spring app using `gradle bootrun`.

I tried to configure aptana to use port `8080` but when I try to access the page it neesd to authenticate in Tomcat server, launched in Spring, probably with a Tomcat user. I don't know this credentials and I couldn't find them anywhere.

Any idea on how to skip this CORS issues so that I can continue my development?

I saw something about some filters in the service app which may, as they say, skip CORS problems. I tried to used a solution but the result is still the same.

**UPDATE 1**

I have a gradle project. I run the project with `gradle bootrun`.

This is my `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">


    <filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ihbs.security.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

</web-app>
```

`CORSFilter`

```
class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I make a call to the server, I never see the `aaaaaa` printed in the console and I can't see those header in the response.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried using the Apache CorsFilter:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I still can't see the headers in the response. I have a feeling that my web.xml file is not in the right place `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`.

I have noticed that the server returns `401` code which is `Unauthorized Access`.

Answer (score 0):

[Enabling CORS on Tomcat](http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html) is easy.

> Apache Tomcat includes support for CORS (Starting from Tomcat version 7.0.41). The full documentation can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Here is an example from those docs that demonstrates a minimal CORS configuration:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```